# How to allow audio to continue to play when app is backgrounded?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, core-audio, avaudiosession

I'm having issues getting audio to play when the app is backgrounded. I have turned on `Background Modes` in Targets>Capabilities, along with checking boxes for the `Audio, Airplay and Picture in Picture` & `Background fetch` modes.

I'm using Core Audio(not sure if that makes a difference). Am i missing a step to get audio to play in the background? Audio plays completely fine when the client is in the foreground, but once the app is backgrounded, audio stops

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you also have an active audio session, code sample is from [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1668/_index.html) Apple Tech Q&A:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
BOOL success = [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryError];
if (!success) { /* handle the error condition */ }

NSError *activationError = nil;
success = [audioSession setActive:YES error:&activationError];
if (!success) { /* handle the error condition */ }
```